# Check to see if String has a Currency symbol before converting it

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string that I'm trying to convert to a decimal which I can do.

Here is the string to convert  1.50 and I run it though the function below and I get back the correct decimal number. But sometimes that string might look like this $1.50, in which case passing to the first function fails. If I pass it to the 2nd function that works, but I need to be able to figure how to determine if the string has a currency symbol. That or maybe combine both functions into one as I think was suggested.

```
func decimalFormat(stringNumber:String) -> Decimal{

    print("\(stringNumber) is the number being passed")
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    let number = numberFormatter.number(from: stringNumber)
    print("\(number!) is the number")

    let amount = number?.decimalValue
    return amount!
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the string has a currency symbol and I would like to check for whatever the local symbol is and then use something like this to convert it

```
 func curencyToDecimal(stringNumber:String) -> Decimal{

    print("\(stringNumber) is the number being passed")
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    let number = numberFormatter.number(from: stringNumber)
    print("\(number!) is the number")

    let amount = number?.decimalValue
    return amount!
}
```

I'm just not sure how to check for the symbol before I try and convert it.

Comment: You could probably use a regex ?

Comment: What about trying both? If the conversion with `.decimal` fails (returns nil) then try the conversion with `.currency`.

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags. [curry-currency-converter] is about some jQuery plugin.

Comment: icekomo, can you provide some examples and expected results?

Comment: @Raymond, I added an example of the String that I would pass to the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to check manually for the currency symbol. You should just change `numberFormatter.numberStyle` to `.currency` if the conversion fails. I would also advise making the function return an optional, since it is possible that the conversion will fail for some input values.

```
func decimalFormat(stringNumber:String) -> Decimal?{

    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    if let number = numberFormatter.number(from: stringNumber) {
        return number.decimalValue
    }
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    if let number = numberFormatter.number(from: stringNumber) {
        return number.decimalValue
    }

    return nil
}
```

The function provides the correct output for below input values using Locale `en_US`.

```
decimalFormat(stringNumber: "123.45") //123.45
decimalFormat(stringNumber: "$123.45") //123.45
```